# Set TFS new workItem state programmatically

Tags: c#, tfs

I'm trying to set tfs new work item state value to "approved" and getting an error.

i'm validating before i actually  save my work item, however the item is not getting because of the errors. The error is because i'm setting a new work item state directly to "Approved" where as it allows only one possible value "Draft".  Unfortunately it's my requirement as i'm migrating my work items from a different source which is already in a "Approved" state.

(TF237124: Work Item is not ready to save).
Fields: The 'State' field has the status InvalidListValue

```
tfsWorkItem.Fields["System.State"].Value = "Approved";
                var invalidFields = tfsWorkItem.Validate();
                if (null == invalidFields || 0 == invalidFields.Count)
                {                        
                    tfsWorkItem.Save(); //Never comes here because of invalidFields
                }
```

Thanks in advance,
Jameel

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TFS 2010 Work Item is not ready to save but there are no validation items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358182/tfs-2010-work-item-is-not-ready-to-save-but-there-are-no-validation-items)

Answer (score 0):

You have to validate the WorkItem prior to save.

The validate() method will return an arraylist of invalid fields.

ArrayList result= wi.Validate();

Comment: Now i'm validating before i actually  save my work item, however the item is not getting because of the errors. The error is because i'm setting a new work item state directly to "Approved" where as it allows only one possible value "Draft".  Unfortunately it's my requirement as i'm migrating my work items from a different source which is already in a "Approved" state.

Answer (score 0):

Original: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8359044/4846465

You are validating the work item before you are changing it's state. Transitioning to a new state can cause Work Item Template actions/rules to be processed. These could be changing the values of some of your fields and/or adding new rules to the fields which would cause the previously valid data to be invalid.

Moving from an Open state to a Closed state might require someone to complete a "Review" field (for example) - if it's empty it cannot transission.

Try validating after the State change and see if there are any failures.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Work Item Template definition XML. In the TRASITIONS section, only the transion that has from="" is the valid starting state (the value in the to="Some state"). There can only be one valid starting state.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your account into "Project Collection Service Accounts" and then enable [bypass rule](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/2013/02/20/tfs-api-part-48-workitemcontrol-and-bypass-work-item-rules/) which allow you to save and change work item values without obeying the work item rules. Refer to this question for details: [How to change workflow state of the newly created TFS work item through API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19981287/how-to-change-workflow-state-of-the-newly-created-tfs-work-item-through-api).